# OpenIMAJ: Maven MojoExecutionException

Tags: java, maven, openimaj

I'm trying to create an OpenIMAJ project following the steps from this source:
http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-openimaj-using-maven.html

I ran the command:

```
mvn -DarchetypeCatalog=http://maven.openimaj.org/archetype-catalog.xml archetype:generate
```

and chose openimaj-quickstart-archetype, a groupID, an artifactID, left version as 1.0-SNAPSHOT, package as such and was able to make a new project successfully.

The default project created by the archetype contains a small “hello world” application which I tried to compile and assemble by:

```
cd trial2
mvn assembly:assembly
```

But the build failed and I got the following error:

```
F:\OpenImaj\trial2>mvn assembly:assembly
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building trial2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) > package @ trial2 >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ trial2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\OpenImaj\trial2\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ trial2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ trial2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\OpenImaj\trial2\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ trial2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ trial2 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: F:\OpenImaj\trial2\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running mec.main_project.group1.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ trial2 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) < package @ trial2 <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) @ trial2 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(Highlighting Build Failure)

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.188 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-12T19:39:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) on project trial2: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

F:\OpenImaj\trial2>
```

Most solutions suggested that I check my java_home variable. It is set correctly:

```
F:\OpenImaj\trial2>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
```

Also, my java version is: `1.8.0_31`

and maven version:

```
F:\OpenImaj\trial2>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30)
Maven home: F:\Apache Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "------", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

What could be the problem for this Build Failure?

Help is much appreciated..
Thanks in Advance

EDIT:
I'm trying to generate the jar-with-dependencies.xml file and this isn't working for me.

Comment: It is actually not just a "possible" duplicate, but that question above is about the same OpenIMAJ project producing the very same error.

Comment: I already went through that question.. I'm in fact trying to generate the jar-with-dependencies.xml file which isn't working for me